# Compile error - having type with an [Application] attribute and an [assembly:Application] attribute

Tags: c#, android

I have a compile error in my *application class*. Here is the code I have in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```csharp
    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("myApp")]
    [assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyProduct("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("CCS")]
    [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

    // The assembly version has the format "{Major}.{Minor}.{Build}.{Revision}".
    // The form "{Major}.{Minor}.*" will automatically update the build and revision,
    // and "{Major}.{Minor}.{Build}.*" will update just the revision.

    [assembly: AssemblyVersion ("0.1.0")]

// The following attributes are used to specify the signing key for the assembly,
// if desired. See the Mono documentation for more information about signing.

//[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
//[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("")]

#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

And this is my application class in `MainActivity.cs`:

```csharp
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Android.App.Application
{

    //public static string globaly = "CSS!";
    public static int AppNr;

    public MyApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        // If OnCreate is overridden, the overridden c'tor will also be called.
        base.OnCreate();
    }
```

I am getting this error message:

> Application cannot have both a type with an [Application] attribute
>   and an [assembly:Application] attribute

Thanks for any advice on how to solve this.

Comment: you could just use [assembly: Debuggable(false, false)] somewhere outside of a namespace

Answer (score 11):

SOLUTION: 
just remove the lines in the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
(#if DEBUG ... #endif)
```

and replace the line

```
[Application]
```

(in your class) with the following one :

```
#if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
    [Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

Comment: @Hrovje I used this but got the error:  "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods, or statements" . Its right after the "true)]"

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered it once, when I deleted below lines and compiled it.

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

Other Way,You can try it

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7670/error-while-preparing-an-application-for-release

Comment: [so] is an English-only site. Please post in English. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/204869), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/1402846), and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove below code from your AssemblyInfo.cs

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

And move them to MyApplication class instead

```
#if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable = true, UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
#else
    [Application(Debuggable = false, UsesCleartextTraffic = false)]
#endif
    public class MyApplication : Android.App.Application
    {

    }
```